# Querying very large xml files

Tags: c#, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I have a merged very large xml file on scale of GB's. I am using following code with xpath queries to read and process data.

```
           IColumn column = output.Schema.FirstOrDefault(col => col.Type != typeof(string));
        if (column != null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Column '{0}' must be of type 'string', not '{1}'", column.Name, column.Type.Name));
        }


        XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
        settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Auto;//.Fragment;
        XmlReader r = XmlReader.Create(input.BaseStream, settings);
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load(r);
        //xmlDocument.LoadXml("<root/>");

        //xmlDocument.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator().AppendChild(r);
        //xmlDocument.Load(input.BaseStream);

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDocument.NameTable);
        if (this.namespaces != null)
        {
            foreach (Match nsdef in xmlns.Matches(this.namespaces))
            {
                string prefix = nsdef.Groups[1].Value;
                string uri = nsdef.Groups[3].Value;
                nsmgr.AddNamespace(prefix, uri);
            }
        }

        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlDocument.DocumentElement.SelectNodes(this.rowPath, nsmgr))
        {
            foreach (IColumn col in output.Schema)
            {
                var explicitColumnMapping = this.columnPaths.FirstOrDefault(columnPath => columnPath.Value == col.Name);
                XmlNode xml = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode(explicitColumnMapping.Key ?? col.Name, nsmgr);
                output.Set(explicitColumnMapping.Value ?? col.Name, xml == null ? null : xml.InnerXml);
            }
            yield return output.AsReadOnly();
        }
```

However it only works well for smaller files on scale of MBs. It works fine locally but fails for ADLA. I need to use the namespace manager as well. How can i scale it so i can process bigger files. On submitting job with huge file I always get this error with no information.

> VertexFailedError

Comment: These files get loaded into RAM - do you have enough?

Comment: It's probably best to use the XmlReader yourself in this case and not read the entire thing into an XmlDocument. It provides fast, forward-only, read access, you can then control what you have in memory rather than the entire xml document. It will probably make the accesses you want to do more complicated, but you at least have a good chance of making them workin.

Comment: @GerardSexton, I have enough RAM to process them locally however, I am not sure about ADL. The file is around 2.7 GB and my local RAM is 32GB. Is there any way for me to check the RAM etc. for jobs.
(PS. very new to u-sql and ADL)

Comment: @moreON I will try that today however I will have to take care of the namespace prefixes etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copying answer I gave in MSDN Forum to same question:

U-SQL Extractors by default are scaled out to work in parallel over smaller parts of the input files, called extents. These extents are about 250MB in size each.

If the data you are processing cannot fit into an extent, you have to tell the extractor with a C# attribute, that the extractor has to see the file in its entirety. You do that by adding the following part ahead of your extractor class:

```
[SqlUserDefinedExtractor(AtomicFileProcessing = true)]
```

Now in your case, XML documents obviously cannot be split since the parser needs to see the beginning and end of a document. This is especially true if you only have a single XML document (side note: Having GBs of a single XML document or JSON document is in my opinion often a bad idea).

Furthermore, I would suggest that you look at the sample XML extractor that we provide on our GitHub site here: https://github.com/Azure/usql/tree/master/Examples/DataFormats

Comment: Thank you Micheal. Yes i had guessed about it from my experiments. I followed the XMLReader sample from git and extended it to support attributes and namespaces for our use case. It worked very well locally as well as with ADL. However, we might have discard it because of atomic file processing behavior. 
Millions of small XML files were merged to form big XML of GBs because of 3000 files limitation.

Comment: If you can concatenate the XML documents by removing all CR LF (or encode them in XML with the character entity) and separate them with CR LF, then you could use a parallel extractor, assuming each XML document is less than 4MB.